# Is there a way to prevent my CSS keyframe animation from starting until that element scrolls in view?

Tags: css-animations, animate.css

I've used keyframes to animate the entrance of some elements onto my page, however the elements are located at the bottom of the page, so the animation takes place before you see them.

Is there a way to stop the animation from happening until the user scrolls into view of the elements? Preferably not a jQuery solution since I am not familiar with it.

Note: I know there is a library called wow.js that solves this issue, but it uses animate.css for it's animations.  This is a problem for me because I was using animate.css originally but it was overwriting/conflicting with some other css I had.  That is why I switched to using keyframes for the animations, and in order to have all the properties of elements working correctly I believe I have to stay with keyframes rather than animate.css

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer! Wow.js still works because you don't have to necessarily use animate.css animations, you can still use your own custom animations.